# Linear regression from scatter Plot in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, linear-regression, scatter-plot

I want to use Linear regression to approximate a scatter plot in Julia.
I used this code as an example:

```
v1 = readdlm("TestFile.txt"; skipstart=2);

scatter(v1[:, 1], v1[:, 2], ms=1, legend=nothing)
```

[image]

The problem is that I am using data from a .txt file. I am not sure how I should tackle my code in order for linear regression to work.

Comment: You could use `GLM.jl` as in https://juliastats.org/GLM.jl/stable/examples/    However, it is totally not clear what you want to do. Maybe you could think about formulating your question to a minimal working example?